# is there any different characteristic between these two crystal?

Tags: pcb, pic, integrated-circuit, microchip, crystal

I have two 12MHz crystal with through-hole package. It is intended to use for MCU crystal.

On top of the crystal, one is written "12.000" and the other is written "E12.000AKDI".

Anybody know what is the different between them???

Sorry if its sound like a very basic question...

Comment: Probably no difference for your application, but without more information I don't think you'll get a useful answer.  Pictures and exact part numbers at a minimum.

Comment: Do you have the data sheets?

Comment: That's the problem, the store only said "12 MHz crystal", no datasheet. I begun suspecting it since my PCB work unstable. I was assuming and expecting there's no different between them and pick the "E12.000AKDI" crystal then have soldered it on my PCB. The crystal connected to PIC24F, and sometimes the PIC stop working in the middle of USB CDC communication. After that the PLL cannot achieve lock, seems like a clock fail occured. I'm still troubleshooting it.

Comment: I have replaced "E12.000AKDI" crystal with "12.000", now the MCU doesn't suffer clock fail anymore, at least up to now it seems working.